# How to change the alpha of a window shown as a sheet?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, cocoa-sheet

In cocoa, do you know how to change the alpha of a window shown as a sheet?
I launch the window with this function and the app always makes the window semi-transparent, I don't want that.

```
- (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)docWindow modalDelegate:(id)modalDelegate didEndSelector:(SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

And no, calling `[[awesomeFantasticWindow window] setAlphaValue:1.0]` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could try setOpaque or setAlphaValue? I know it's silly but figured I'd start with the easy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your own custom view as the window's content view and set its color to whatever you want.